# Is it possible to save a video stream between two peers in webrtc in the server, realtime?

Tags: webrtc, video-conferencing, agora.io

Suppose I have 2 peers exchanging video with webRTC. Now I need both of the streams to be saved as video files in the central server. Is is possible to do it realtime? (Storing/Uploading the video from peers is not an option).

I thought of making a 3 node webRTC connection, with the **3rd node** being the **server**. This way, I can screen record the 3rd node's stream or save it using some other way. But I am not sure about the reliability/feasibility of the implementation.

This is for a mobile application, and I would **avoid** any method that involves uploading/saving.

PS: I'm using **Agora.io** for the purpose of video-conference.

Comment: Is it possible with webRTC?

Answer (score 3):

in my opinion
you can do it like the record demo:https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/.

record each stream to blobs and push them to your server with websocket.

then convert the blobs to a webm file or just add in a video

Comment: How can I add in a video?

Comment: use ffmpeg is the best choice. docs here:https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Answer (score 1):

Agora doesn't offer on-premise recording out of the box but they do provide thee code for you to be able to launch your own on-premise recording using your own server. Agora has the code and instructions to deploy on GitHub: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Recording

The way it works, once you have set up the Agora Recording SDK, the client would trigger the recording to start, via user interaction *(button tap)* or some other event *(i.e. `peer-joined` or `stream-subscribed`)* this will trigger the recording service to join the channel and record the streams. _The service outputs the video file once recording has stopped.

Comment: what about recording session in reactjs

Answer (score 0):

> you need a WebRTC media server.
>
> WebRTC media servers makes it possible to support more complex
> scenarios WebRTC media servers are servers that act as WebRTC clients
> but run on the server side. They are termination points for the media
> where we’d like to take action. Popular tasks done on WebRTC media
> servers include:
>
> Group calling Recording Broadcast and live streaming Gateway to other
> networks/protocols Server-side machine learning Cloud rendering
> (gaming or 3D) The adventurous and strong hearted will go and develop
> their own WebRTC media server. Most would pick a commercial service or
> an open source one. For the latter, check out these tips for choosing
> WebRTC open source media server framework.
>
> In many cases, the thing developers are looking for is support for
> group calling, something that almost always requires a media server.
> In that case, you need to decide if you’d go with the classing (and
> now somewhat old) MCU mixing model or with the more accepted and
> modern SFU routing model. You will also need to think a lot about the
> sizing of your WebRTC media server.
>
> For recording WebRTC sessions, you can either do that on the client
> side or the server side. In both cases you’ll be needing a server, but
> what that server is and how it works will be very different in each
> case.
>
> If it is broadcasting you’re after, then you need to think about the
> broadcast size of your WebRTC session.

link:https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-server/